# Assistance with Matching Data in two different data frames

Tags: pandas, fuzzy-search

I am trying to find the closest matching result of each row of data (based off of Company Name and Address) in one smaller dataframe (n=3,900 Rows) in a larger master dataframe (n=1,400,000 rows)

I built it in Python using the Jellyfish and Pandas Packages.

However, while the code does run, it takes 6+ hours to complete.

Would anyone have any tips for speeding the output up faster?

Or rather, is there a better alternative than using a nested 'for' loop?

Thanks! - Also this is my first Python Programme

```html
import re
import jellyfish
import pandas as pd
Input = pd.read_csv('InputData.csv')
Match =  pd.read_csv('MasterData.csv')


for row in Input.itertuples():
    for row2 in Match.itertuples():
#match between Addresses and Names Columns in both dataframes is more than 69% - Match
            if jellyfish.jaro_distance(str(row[2]).lower(),str(row2[3]).lower()) >= 0.69 and jellyfish.jaro_distance(str(row[4]).lower(), str(row2[5]).lower()) >= 0.69:
                Input.at[row.Index, "Result"] = "Exact Match"
#match between Addresses and Name Columns are both less than 69% - No Match
            elif jellyfish.jaro_distance(str(row[2]).lower(),str(row2[3]).lower()) < 0.69 and jellyfish.jaro_distance(str(row[4]).lower(), str(row2[5]).lower()) < 0.69
                Input.at[row.Index, "Result"] = "Nothing Matching" 

#Where row[2] is the Company Name Column, row2[3] is the Master Data Company Name Column, 
row[4] is the Company Name Address Column and row2[5] is the Master Company Name Address Column
```

Comment: Quick tip: convert your input and match data sets to string and lower case once at the start, before doing anything else. Right now you're converting each entry anew in every iteration of your inner loop, which is unnecessary and slows down your computation. Fixing this will not solve the larger problem, but will definitely help.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, you can simplify the 'elif' statement to just an 'else' statement (so without the jaro distance calculation etc), since you're clearly only interested in the opposite of the 'if' condition to be true. This will save you some more time.